# Save sensible data in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a connection with redis, that it's protected by password. But if I put my password on js, it is readable and insecure, such as If i put my pass in main.js like:

```
var redis = new Redis({
    port: 5008,
    host: 'mysite.com',
    protocol: "https",
    password: "mypasswordencryptedhere"
  })
```

If i compile my app with electron-packager and I look at the folder created, I'm able to read main.js with password.
So, my question is, where Can I store a sensible data like password in electron?
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shortly - on server with database.**

I used this approach
I have made web application with API endpoint, that was called by clients application. API received from clients application the `AppID` - unique  string (there was 1 to 1 relations between application users and AppIDs), and than, based on this `AppID` and some proprientary code i never shared, it received a unique API connection string, that can be used in application.
And, this connection string was generated each time user tried to receive access to database.

This approach have this downsides - you need server running with API of your application. Since, you have mentioned, that you use electron, it is likely that you have some nodejs skills and can make the API server.

UPD: we are reinventing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth Protocol. I think it will be better to use it for receiving one time passwords for electron app to access api

Comment: Hello vodolaz! thankyou, yes, I have an Api endpoit build on Laravel where I make a Ajax call for retrieve data with a ApiKey stored dinamically on setting and when I make a ajax call I check if ApiKey is valid and assigned, so Can I a simple ajax call on my server and return password? 
I had thought of this method but do not know if it was a valid method

Comment: i think it wiill be valid method, if there are ONE API KEY for ONE USER, no duplicate api keys. Maybe you can find any libraries to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth authorization

Comment: Yes, I have make a JWT AUth for login, and when Icreate user I assign, unique static APIKEY (256char) for user, that it use for Electron App